# Recursive fib function, Incorrect output, cannot find what is causing error

Tags: recursion, assembly, riscv

I am a beginner at assembly, and I am trying to create a Fibonacci function. I have tried debugging my code and written the code incrementally, making sure it would run after each line of code I put. By doing this I was able to fix the compilation errors, but I am not sure why I keep receiving the wrong output which should be 13 but instead is 4 (input is 7). I am not sure what is causing it and what I should do to fix it. Here is the code I've written in RV64I:

```
# main function


main:
    li x10, 7          # Load immediate value 7 into register x10
    jal ra, fib        # Jump and link to the fib function
    li x17, 10         # Load immediate value 10 into register x17
    ecall              # System call (end of program)

# fib function
fib:
    addi sp, sp, -16   # Allocate 16 bytes on the stack
    sd ra, 8(sp)       # Save the return address on the stack at offset 8
    sd x10, 0(sp)      # Save the value of x10 on the stack at offset 0
    bnez x10, elif     # Branch if x10 is not equal to zero

    li x10, 0          # Load immediate value 0 into register x10
    addi sp, sp, 16    # Deallocate 16 bytes from the stack
    jr ra              # Jump to the return address (end of function)

elif:
    li x28, 1          # Load immediate value 1 into register x28
    bne x10, x28, else # Branch if x10 is not equal to x28

    li x10, 1          # Load immediate value 1 into register x10
    addi sp, sp, 16    # Deallocate 16 bytes from the stack
    jr ra              # Jump to the return address (end of function)

else:
    addi x10, x10, -1  # Subtract 1 from the value of x10
    jal fib           # Jump and link to the fib function (commented out)
    mv x29, x10        # Move the value of x10 into register x29
 
    ld x10, 0(sp)      # Load the saved value of x10 from the stack
    addi x10, x10, -2  # Subtract 2 from the value of x10
    jal fib           # Jump and link to the fib function (commented out)
    add x10, x29, x10  # Add the value of x29 and x10, and store the result in x10

    ld ra, 8(sp)       # Load the saved return address from the stack
    addi sp, sp, 16    # Deallocate 16 bytes from the stack
    jr ra              # Jump to the return address (end of function)
```

Here is the C++ version of the fib function I was trying to create in assembly:

```
int fib(int n)
{ 
    if (n==0) return 0; 
    else if (n == 1) return 1;
    else return fib(n−1) + fib(n−2);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For many situations, I would have said to run the debugger and see what's going wrong.  However, when function calling is involved, there's a lot to pay attention to on a single function call, and you have to look at it from two perspectives — did the function call work (i.e. step in and see it work and provides the proper return value) and also, *did the function call properly restore the environment for the caller (i.e. register values, including stack pointer)*, which is more of a "step over" notion from the continuity of the caller's context.

To debug this kind of thing yourself, you might observe that `fib(0)`, `fib(1)`, `fib(2)` all work (though `fib(2)` sort of by accident), and `fib(3)` doesn't, so that's where to focus debugging.  The idea is to build up test cases from the simplest possible to, when those are working, slightly larger.

Function calling is difficult with all its moving parts, and recursion, though adding no rules or other overhead beyond ordinary function calling, gets confusing to keep track of, since by its nature there will be multiple stack frames involved.

---

Your register usage is not following the calling convention — however, to be clear though code should follow the calling convention, that is not the specific flaw — the problem is that you are putting multiple values into x29 and expecting the older values to magically reappear even though they've been wiped out.

The registers are effectively (fast) global variables.  So, if one `fib` sets x29 to some value, then a 2nd recursive call does the same, the 2nd recursive call "wins", it wipes out x29 for the prior/greater recursive calls.  The value in x29, is that of whomever set it last, when the 1st recursive call is resumed, which your code is not expecting.

---

As an aside, your usage of x register numbers instead of friendly register names is unreadable, and further you're mixing friendly names (e.g. `ra`) with x numbers.  If you want to write readable code, stick to the friendly register names and avoid the x register numbers (except perhaps the special x0).

---

What you're looking for from `x29` is the concept of a call-preserved register.  The `x29` number refers to `t4`, which is not a call-preserved register by the convention, and what you should be using is one of the `s` registers instead, say `s0`.  However, simply changing the register is insufficient, as the magic to make the `s` registers call-preserved is done with code, which you also need to add.

To make `s0` work, you'll need an extra word of stack space, and to save and restore `s0` in the prologue and epilogue.  The idea of the call preserved registers is that you don't know what you're saving & restoring, but you know that if you do that then you can then use the register in a way that is preserved across a call.

---

---

As a wholly separate alternative, you can avoid the `s` registers and simply save the `fib` return value into stack.  This will also require an additional word of stack space, but this time the word is not used to save/restore in prologue epilogue, but rather to simply save a value from the first `fib` into the stack, then reload it after the 2nd call to `fib`.

Using this approach you're saving the (return) value needed later, after a function call (the 2nd to `fib`) in memory, and stack memory survives function calls.  This approach of using memory is actually simpler than the call-preserved register approach, but only for very simply functions like recursive `fib`.  If the function does more work (i.e. has a loop or more function calling), then the `s` register approach will become a net win.

---

The astute reader may realize that the stack space used to save the incoming `a0` value can be reused to store the 1st `fib`'s return value, meaning that the function only needs the two (64-bit) words of stack space.  In order for this to work, the value in memory after the 1st fib call needs to be reloaded to registers *before* the store of the return value.

That means that between the 2 recursive `fib` calls:

- reload the original `a0` value into `a1` — `a1` because `a0` still holds the return value needed later
- store the `a0` (return) value into that memory slot, now that this slot is no longer needed
- compute into `a0` the value of `a1-2` for the parameter for the 2nd `fib` call.

After the 2nd recursive call, reload the stack-saved value in order to compute the final return value.

Comment: thanks for all the help. since i'm new to assembly i'm a bit confused about what you mean for epilogue and prologue, would the epilogue be at the very start of the function and the prologue be at the end of the function right before I dellocate the bytes from the stack?

Comment: Yes, you have the right idea.  The prologue is at the start of the function and performs stack allocation and saving of registers as needed, and the epilogue un-does that (restoring registers then deallocation stack space) and also returns to the caller.

Comment: @ErikEidt: if you're going to write a guide on debugging recursive functions on some random question like this, you should at least make sure it's tagged [recursion], and has a useful title that will let future readers find it again.  (And you, when you want to link it).  I'd edit myself but I'm [semi on strike](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425000/moderation-strike-stack-overflow-inc-cannot-consistently-ignore-mistreat-an), avoiding interacting with questions that don't interest me instead of my usual curation edits.